# Auzentech X-Fi Prelude doesn't remember settings

Tags: windows-7, sound-card

I'm running Windows 7 RC x64 on my new computer, and my sound card does not remember settings.

Every time I reboot, I have to go back into the Audio Console and set everything back to where I want it, as it defaults to it's super defaults.

Relevant specs:

- Windows 7 RC x64
- Asus P5N72-T Premium Mobo w/ latest drivers
- eVGA Nvidia 295 w/ latest drivers
- Auzentech X-Fi prelude w/ Daniel_k drivers (Creative Labs ones didn't allow me to do anything, like change modes, or even set to 5.1)

Anybody experience this or know what's up? It's not a huge problem, but really annoying.

I do remember trying this originally with the Creative Labs drivers, and the same problem occurred.

Comment: Well at least I got the Tumbleweed badge...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading my drivers to the what Auzentech had for the latest fixed this.